# changing xml values takes as a string in java

Tags: java, xml, string

```
String
-------------------
<DslOrder index="1422796670990">
<orderId index="1422796671001">123456</orderId>
<AsdlServiceDetails index="1422796670991">
<bandwidth index="1422796670993">45678</bandwidth>
</AsdlServiceDetails>
<SubscriberInfo index="1422796670994">
<Address index="1422796670996">

<City index="1422796670999">MO</City>

<PostalCode index="1422796670998">456</PostalCode>

<Street index="1422796670997">sdfghh</Street>

</Address>

<PhoneNumber index="1422796671000">45678</PhoneNumber>

<Name index="1422796670995">sedrtfgh</Name>

</SubscriberInfo>

</DslOrder>
```

I have thisString With me. I need to change the value of the String in between Xml Elements.
How do I Achieve this Dynamically.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your expected result? Which elements do you like to change?

Comment: I want to change <PhoneNumber> tag and want to add another tag  and need to change value of name from sedrtfgh to another and finally return this in form of string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can solve this by using [data projection](http://xmlbeam.org) (Disclosure: I'm affiliated with that project). You can define a "projection" (that is something like a view) to the xml data. This projection is an interface that defines methods to read, create update or delete stuff from the XML. What is to be done is declared with XPath expressions:

```
public class DSLOrder {

    private final static String XML_BEFORE="<DslOrder index=\"1422796670990\">\n" + 
            "<orderId index=\"1422796671001\">123456</orderId>\n" + 
            "<AsdlServiceDetails index=\"1422796670991\">\n" + 
            "<bandwidth index=\"1422796670993\">45678</bandwidth>\n" + 
            "</AsdlServiceDetails>\n" + 
            "<SubscriberInfo index=\"1422796670994\">\n" + 
            "<Address index=\"1422796670996\">\n" + 
            "<City index=\"1422796670999\">MO</City>\n" + 
            "<PostalCode index=\"1422796670998\">456</PostalCode>\n" + 
            "<Street index=\"1422796670997\">sdfghh</Street>\n" + 
            "</Address>\n" + 
            "<PhoneNumber index=\"1422796671000\">45678</PhoneNumber>\n" + 
            "<Name index=\"1422796670995\">sedrtfgh</Name>\n" + 
            "</SubscriberInfo>\n" + 
            "</DslOrder>";


    public interface Projection {
        // Define any methods for manipulation here       
        @XBUpdate("/DslOrder/SubscriberInfo/PhoneNumber")
        void updatePhoneNumber(String newNumber);

        // Define any methods for manipulation here       
        @XBUpdate("/DslOrder/SubscriberInfo/Name")
        void updateName(String newName);

        @XBWrite("/DslOrder/SubscriberInfo/additionalTag")
        void createAdditionalTag(String value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Projection projection = new XBProjector(Flags.TO_STRING_RENDERS_XML).onXMLString(XML_BEFORE).createProjection(Projection.class);
        projection.updatePhoneNumber("12345");
        projection.updateName("New Name");
        projection.createAdditionalTag("value for new tag");
        System.out.println(projection.toString());
    }
}
```

This program prints out:

```
<DslOrder index="1422796670990">
<orderId index="1422796671001">123456</orderId>
<AsdlServiceDetails index="1422796670991">
<bandwidth index="1422796670993">45678</bandwidth>
</AsdlServiceDetails>
<SubscriberInfo index="1422796670994">
<Address index="1422796670996">
<City index="1422796670999">MO</City>
<PostalCode index="1422796670998">456</PostalCode>
<Street index="1422796670997">sdfghh</Street>
</Address>
<PhoneNumber index="1422796671000">12345</PhoneNumber>
<Name index="1422796670995">New Name</Name>
<additionalTag>value for new tag</additionalTag>
  </SubscriberInfo>
</DslOrder>
```

Of course you need to add the methods to the projection that do what you need. These projection methods can even have parameters to be used in the XPath expressions (dynamic projections).